# Invite other scholars to the forum

Tags: discussion

Could you invite people who you know are knowledgable and can answer questions really well in the light of islam? We need experts. They will be a great asset to this site?

Are there ways where we can use this feature responsibly?

Answer (score 2):

You can invite whoever you like to the site, particularly if you think they would be interested and able to contribute to its growth and development. Once the site has passed into public beta, you can just send them a link; until then, you'll find a form on [the front page](https://islam.stackexchange.com/) that'll let you send them an invitation to the private beta:

[image: the invitation form]

Answer (score 0):

I believe we are all free to invite anyone to the site, once it passes into a public beta. There are no rules of guidelines in that matter, nor there should be.

Answer (score 0):

My question was more about effective ways to invite people that can contribute to the site. This is what I would suggest

1. Invite your friend who you think are into Islam. They will be a great resource.
2. Invite your Imam of mosque or any scholar you think can be an asset.
3. Searching online and look for prominent Muslim scholars. Find out their emails and and invitation. Nothing can go wrong because if there email is not valid, it simply is ignored.
4. Try to find every problem we face and ask questions about it. It does not necessarily be your own question. Ask question that your friends once asked.